# error from IE9 while creating UserManager in oidc-client.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, identityserver3

I have the following lines in my app.js file:

```
var settings = {
    ...
    ...
};

alert('1);
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(settings);
alert('2');
...
```

Everything works great in every browser except IE9 (and below).

In IE9 '1' comes up and then I get javascript error:
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'

Is it something I am doing wrong or for it to work it must be IE version > 9?

Thank you

Mark

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? Having the same problem. thx.